# How to change the font size of easyui

Tags: jquery-easyui

How can I change font size for all cells:

I tried below but no effect.

```
<syle>
.datagrid-cell {
    font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: Go into a bit more detail on what's going on, what you've tried, and what you're trying to do.

Comment: i just want to change the font size of esayui,it's too small